# How does the update diff work in AzerothCore?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, azerothcore

The `worldserver` source code is full of `Update` methods that take as input a `diff` integer value:

[image: AzerothCore Update(uint32 diff)]

How does it work?

And how is this linked to the "**Update time diff**" from the `.server info` command?

[image: AzerothCore .server info command]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully understand how this works, it's necessary to have a look at the main World run process.

### WorldRunnable::run()

File: [src/server/worldserver/WorldThread/WorldRunnable.cpp](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/worldserver/WorldThread/WorldRunnable.cpp)

The method `void WorldRunnable::run()` is the "*Main heartbeat for the World*". This method runs the whole world process.

Inside it, there is a `while` loop that runs as long as the world is supposed to keep running:

```cpp
void WorldRunnable::run()
{
    uint32 realCurrTime = 0;
    uint32 realPrevTime = getMSTime();

    ///- While we have not World::m_stopEvent, update the world
    while (!World::IsStopped())
    {
        ++World::m_worldLoopCounter;
        realCurrTime = getMSTime();

        uint32 diff = getMSTimeDiff(realPrevTime, realCurrTime);

        sWorld->Update( diff );
        realPrevTime = realCurrTime;

        uint32 executionTimeDiff = getMSTimeDiff(realCurrTime, getMSTime());
        devDiffTracker.Update(executionTimeDiff);
        avgDiffTracker.Update(executionTimeDiff > WORLD_SLEEP_CONST ? executionTimeDiff : WORLD_SLEEP_CONST);

        // ... some more code here
    }
    // at this point the world process is terminating

    // ... some more code here
```

What this loop really does is basically:

1) calculate the elapsed time (**in milliseconds**) since the previous iteration, this will be the `diff`

2) call the `sWorld->Update( diff );` function, that contains all the world process logic (see below) and passing the `diff` to it

3) calculate how much time it took to run `sWorld->Update( diff );` and update the `devDiffTracker` and its average `avgDiffTracker`. These values will be displayed by the `.server info` command.

### World::Update(uint32 diff)

File: [src/server/game/World/World.cpp](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/game/World/World.cpp)

The `World::Update(uint32 diff)` function gets constantly called by the main worldserver loop process and every time it takes in input the amount `diff` of elapsed time since the last call.

This function is responsible for constantly updating the world, this is where all the magic happens.

#### Timers

There are a set of timers (defined in [World.h](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/game/World/World.h) that are being updated within the `World::Update` function:

```
/// Timers for different object refresh rates
enum WorldTimers
{
    WUPDATE_AUCTIONS,
    WUPDATE_WEATHERS,
    WUPDATE_UPTIME,
    WUPDATE_CORPSES,
    WUPDATE_EVENTS,
    WUPDATE_CLEANDB,
    WUPDATE_AUTOBROADCAST,
    WUPDATE_MAILBOXQUEUE,
    WUPDATE_PINGDB,
    WUPDATE_5_SECS,
    WUPDATE_COUNT
};
```

For example, `WUPDATE_AUTOBROADCAST` is responsible for the period global messages defined in the [acore_auth.autobroadcast](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/autobroadcast) table.

#### Tasks

The `World::Update` function also takes care of many timed-tasks, for example:

```cpp
/// Handle daily quests reset time
if (m_gameTime > m_NextDailyQuestReset)
    ResetDailyQuests();
```

#### Calling Update(diff) functions of Managers

In AzerothCore there are singleton classes called Managers (Mgr) that handle specific parts of the game. For example `BattlegroundMgr` handles the Battlegrounds (BGs).

Those classes have their own `Update(uint32 diff)` functions and they are called by `World::Update` that passes down the `diff` to them, for example:

```cpp
sBattlegroundMgr->Update(diff);
sOutdoorPvPMgr->Update(diff);
sBattlefieldMgr->Update(diff);
/// ... there are more!
```

#### OnWorldUpdate hook

Last but not least, it calls `sScriptMgr->OnWorldUpdate(diff);`.

This is part of the [AzerothCore Module System](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/The-Modular-Structure), and defines a hook that can be used by third-part modules to attach custom logic to the `World::Update` function.